# SMPS buck convrter with PWM controller circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, pwm, switch-mode-power-supply, buck

[image: SMPS]

Hi there

I am designing a buck converter run on PWM circuitry for a uni project to drive a MOSFET switch and keep my output voltage constant.

The specs are:

- input voltage of 20v DC +/- 4
- output voltage of 5v DC
- Maximum output current of 1A
- No more than 10% change in voltage over entire range of input voltage and load
- Min. 80% efficiency at full load
- No micro-controllers can be used

Here is what I have so far, but its not simulating right.

please help

Comment: When you say "not simulating right", what exactly is the problem? How did you set up the simulation? What result did you expect? How is the actual result different?

Comment: Downvoting because you didn't bother to say what the problem is.

Comment: Please edit your question and actually ask a question: then go read this http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask otherwise your questions will be downvoted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Min. 80% efficiency at full load

- Not with an N channel MOSFET source follower circuit as the switcher - you need a P channel rewired as common source.
- Not with a 741 op-amp driving the MOSFET (gate capacitance = 6.8nF). Just don't use that dinosaur of an op-amp. In fact you'll need a high speed buffer between the op-amp and the MOSFET to be able to deliver several hundred mA into the gate capacitance.